# io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 error

Tags: android, webview, ktor

Answear of my ktor post request is HTML page.  I have answear io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
How to fix it?

[image]

Code of my request:
`class GetThreeDsApi @Inject constructor(
private val httpClient: HttpClient,
) : KtorApiRequest<AcsRedirect, Response> {

```
override suspend fun execute(
    acsRedirect: AcsRedirect,
): Response<String> {
    return getApiContentSafeOperation<String> {
        httpClient.post("${acsRedirect.url}") {
            setBody(
                MultiPartFormDataContent(
                    formData {
                        append(
                            HttpHeaders.ContentType,
                            "multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary"
                        )
                        append("PaReq", "${acsRedirect.postParameters?.paReq}")
                        append("TermUrl", "${acsRedirect.postParameters?.termUrl}")
                        append("MD", "${acsRedirect.postParameters?.md}")
                    },
                    boundary = "WebAppBoundary"
                )
            )
        }.body<String>()
    }
}
```

}`